# Angular 6 : PrimeNG Tab View : How to preserve state when move between tab panel

Tags: angular, primeng

In Angular 6 application, I'm using PrimeNG Tabview control. There are two tab panel. One is for search and second is for customer listing. My requirement is once I search something on first panel and move between two panel then I don't want to loose data what I've searched on first panel.

In primeNG Tabview there's cache property but It's for lazy loading only.

Following is sample code.

```
<p-tabView class="customDatatable" (onChange)="onTabChange($event)">
    <p-tabPanel header="{{userProf.getStaticLabel('searchlist')}}">
        <div id="a-searchlist"></div>
    </p-tabPanel>
    <p-tabPanel header="{{userProf.getStaticLabel('customerlist')}}">
        <div id="b-customerlist"></div>
    </p-tabPanel>
</p-tabView>
```

I want to keep onChange event to refresh the customerlist everytime I click on that tab.

If need more code please do let me know so I will copy whole my code for your reference.

Comment: can you provide stackblitz?

Comment: cn you provide more code , how do you search and  how the searchList is related to customerList ? 

Comment: Please provide your code